# Is it possible to center an image with an animation from an XML file?

Tags: android, xml, animation, imageview, center

I have no problem to do this with java code, but i'm wondering if it's possible to center an imageView thanks to an XML animation file.
Indeed, my ImageView is in a linearlayout with a margin of 100dp, at the top right of the screen, so when I do this, the image is not centered but at 100dp from top and right centered :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="50%p"
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:fillEnabled="false" 
    android:fillAfter="true">
</translate>
```

EDIT: my imageView, "cardsPileImage" is in this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/board_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardsPileImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true">
        </ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="@string/start_game"
                android:onClick="startGame">
            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/discardPileImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true">
        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks you per advance :-)

Comment: Put your layout xml code also where you have define the Imageview.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer : it's done :-)

Comment: I am not getting you what you actualy want. Please clerify your question.

Comment: I am able to solve your issue but i am not understanding what you want.

Comment: I want that my image view go at the center of the screen with a translate animation. With the code that I have given, the image go to the x center - 100dp and to the y center - 100dp.

Comment: Which ImageView you want to translate at center ? You are using two ImageView.

Comment: The image with the id "cardsPileImage"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can able to do that.

But for that you have to take the RelativeLayout as because LinearLayout will not able to do this for your case.

Why you take the linearLayout for all times and for all other view ??

Just use this xml with your translate animation and try it.

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:id="@+id/board_layout"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:background="#FFFFFF"     
    android:orientation="vertical">      

    <ImageView             
        android:id="@+id/cardsPileImage"             
        android:layout_width="100dp"             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"             
        android:layout_gravity="right"             
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"             
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">         
    </ImageView>

     <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardsPileImage"                 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/backButton"                 
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"                 
        android:paddingRight="60dp"                 
        android:textSize="25dp"                 
        android:text="Start Game"                 
        android:onClick="startGame">             
    </Button>          

    <ImageView             
        android:id="@+id/discardPileImage"   
        android:layout_below="@+id/backButton"          
        android:layout_width="100dp"             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:src="@drawable/icon"             
        android:layout_gravity="right"             
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"             
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"             
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">         
    </ImageView>      

</RelativeLayout>
```

If it not works then let me know. :)

**Updated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:id="@+id/board_layout"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:background="#FFFFFF">      

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView             
            android:id="@+id/cardsPileImage"             
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"             
            android:layout_gravity="right"     
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
            >         
        </ImageView>
        <Button
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardsPileImage"                 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:id="@+id/backButton"                 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"                 
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Start Game"                 
            android:onClick="startGame">             
        </Button>          

        <ImageView             
            android:id="@+id/discardPileImage"   
            android:layout_below="@+id/backButton"          
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:src="@drawable/icon"             
            android:layout_gravity="right"    
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"       
            >         
        </ImageView>      

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but your layout is not like mine. I don't know how to do the same with a relative layout.
I need a button and two images : button in center, first image at top right, second image at bottom right. The background of all the screen need to be set to a drawable and the margin of all over the screen need to be 100dp.

Comment: Its realy so simple. Ok Let me try for you if i can get time. But for that you have to wait . . . And Give some instruction what you exactly want.

Comment: No, because my image view is at left and the animation translate it to the right... (-50%). With 50%, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please see the Updated Answer. I have set the Layout in RelativeLayout as per your requirement.

Comment: What you want to do with the Animation ?

Comment: I mean you want to overlap the ImageView on the Button ?

Comment: When the animation will start, the button visibility will be View.INVISIBLE. So no, i don't want to overlap the imageView on the button.

Comment: I have seen your updated answer, your layout don't do the same as my layout visible in my question. ImageViews are not in top right and bottom right of screen but at top and bottom of the button.
Thanks for your help anyway, hope we'll find a way :-)

Comment: I have change some properties Just now. check it on Updated xml layout.